# In Firestore, do the security rules kick in before the collection snapshot updates?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a where-expression on a collection and listen to updates. I use the exact same expression to grant read access. When the where-condition no longer holds for a document i would expect it to be removed from my snapshot, but an exception is thrown referencing the permission rules.

My rule looks like this

```
match /arenas/{arenaId}/channels/{channelId} {
  allow read :  if (request.auth.uid in resource.data.members);
}
```

My listener is setup like this

```
ref
    .collection("channels")
    .where("members", "array-contains", uid)
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
```

When i take an `id` out of `members` for a specific channel, the where-expression no longer holds for that particular channel. Instead of an update that notifies me that the channel is removed i get an exception.

Is this the expected behaviour, or am i making a mistake?

If it *is* expected, what would the correct implementation be, or how could i work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  If, at any time, conditions change that *would* result in a security rule rejecting a new query, any *existing* listeners of that same query will be immediately rejected with an error.  A listener can't live beyond its welcome, as far as security rules are concerned.

I can't recommend a "correct" implementation, as you'll have to figure out for yourself what to do if the listener fails.  Perhaps you can try the query again after correcting the list of UIDs.

Comment: Thank you. I would actually expect this to be a common use case. "Read all documents in a collection i am a member of, and deny any access to the rest"

Comment: That's not possible, because security rules are not filters.  The query must **exactly** match the constraints of the rule.  Read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters

Comment: Yes exactly. And i my case the rule and filter are an exact match. The filter checks if a users id is in a list, and so does the security rule.

Comment: But you said the resource changed and no longer matches the query?

Comment: Ah, poor explanation: I change the resource by removing the user id from the list of members. Then the where expression should filter out the resource, so security shouldn't have to kick in.

Comment: If you think there's a bug in the way security rules work, then I suggest filing your specific reproduction steps with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support