# Unexpected getting cloud_firestore/permission-denied in production sometimes

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Firestore rule:

```
match /app/info {
  allow read;
}
```

My code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('app')
        .doc('info')
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
        (event) {
          final _minVersion = event.data()?['min_version'];
          if (_minVersion is! String) return;
          shouldUpdateApp(Version.parse(_minVersion), context.appLoc);
        },
        onError: (Object error, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
          FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
            error,
            stackTrace,
            reason: 'app info onError',
          );
        },
      )
```

And is working perfectly in development.

However, sometimes in production I get errors reported to Firebase Crashlytics.

> Non-fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError
>
> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.. Error thrown app info onError.

---

**Update 18 May 2022:**

This only happens when the device is 100% running in background.

Comment: Hello, is app/info the only path you access? And do you only perform read operations in all places of the App?

Comment: Hi. I only added the path I am having errors from. Yes  app/info is the only path i want to read and is working perfectly when i test but sometimes i get permission errors for some reason due to this path.

Comment: Is this `info` document a read-only document? Or do you write to it from a different source (other clients, the admin SDK)? I ask because you attach a listener that returns changes that happen on this document. I suspect your scenario could be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70968013/) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512058/), where async writes and reads can sometimes trigger your Firebase rules as documents change or are created. Also, is your rule snippet the same as used in your production environment?

Comment: It's a read-only document and I do not write anything to it. It only listens to the document case the min version is greater than current one, will force the user to update the app through google play/app store. I only write to it manually through firebase console, when I want to force an update.